# Qt, linux, adding build date and time define

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to get the build date and time into my application so I can display in the about page.

In my pro file I have:

```
    DEFINES += "BUILDDATE=$$system(date +'%d-%m-%y %T')"
```

I've tried the date command with the format in a terminal on the system and it works fine.

In my source:

```
    QString strBldDate(BUILDDATE);
```

This all builds without error, when I check in the debugger, strBldDate is empty.

From discussions I've been told I can use message() in the ".pro" file to show for example:

```
    message($$system(date +"'%d-%m-%y %T'"))
```

This works and when I build I get something like:

```
    Project MESSAGE: 26-06-19 10:34:59
```

But how can I use the same to validate the contents of a definition?

```
    message(BUILDDATE)
```

After my above efforts just results in:

```
    Project MESSAGE: BUILDDATE
```

Comment: @MartinBonner, sorry you are right, corrected now.

Comment: What does `message($$system(date +'%d-%m-%y %T')` show?  In fact, what does `message(date +'%d-%m-%y %T')` show?

Comment: @MartinBonner, interestingly in Qt Creator I get a warning on the date format, however if I copy "date +'%d-%m-%y %T' and paste into the terminal it works.  From just running it:  26-06-19 08:41:22

Comment: Also, does it work if you use `BUILDDATE = $$system(date +'%d-%m-%y %T')` and `DEFINES += "BUILDDATE=$$BUILDDATE"`?

Comment: SPlatten - Qt Creator is probably treating the date format as a printf string so it isn't valid.

Comment: @MartinBonner, trying now, what does that do?

Comment: @MartinBonner,  still empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195562/discussion-between-martin-bonner-and-splatten).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You actually could just use standard predefined macros for this in GCC and in MSVC.

Here is a list of predef macros in GCC: [3.7.1 Standard Predefined Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html)

And for MSVC: [Predefined Macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019)

Code could look something like this:

```
QString datetime = QStringLiteral(__DATE__) + QStringLiteral(" ") + QStringLiteral(__TIME__);
```

If you can't use predefined macros, just don't use empty spaces in definitions and pack it with backslash quote like this:

```
DEFINES += BUILDDATE=\\\"$$system( date "+%d.%m.%Y_%H:%M:%S" )\\\"

strBldDate.replace(QChar('_'), QChar(' '));
```

**EDIT:**
Create **builddatetime.h** file and include it everywhere you need your build version:

```
#ifndef BUILDDATETIME_H
#define BUILDDATETIME_H

#include <QString>
const QString BUILDV =  QStringLiteral(__DATE__ " " __TIME__);

#endif // BUILDDATETIME_H
```

In your .pro file add **builddatetime.h** to headers (`HEADERS += builddatetime.h`)
And the following lines:

```
buildtimeTarget.target = builddatetime.h
buildtimeTarget.depends = FORCE
buildtimeTarget.commands = touch $$PWD/builddatetime.h
PRE_TARGETDEPS += builddatetime.h
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += buildtimeTarget
```

This will touch **builddatetime.h** and all cpp files which include this header will be rebuild on each build and run command.

Comment: Important thing to notice about this approach: it will get the date that particular compilation unit was built last. So if there are no changes, it won't be rebuilt and time and date won't change.  This might be solved by using *touch* or *rm* or maybe just doing clean build when necessary.

Comment: @hyde, right. This could be fixed with --always-make for make, or PHONY/FORCE. Or just adding Pre-Build Event in Qt's .pro file

Comment: This isn't the solution I'm looking for as __DATE__ and __TIME__ are only relative to the source module that are used in, I want the BUILD date and time for the entire project.

Comment: `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` are standard macros, so no need to point to compiler-specific docs, it's sufficient to point to the [C++ draft text for `__DATE__`](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.predefined#1.2) and [for `__TIME__`](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.predefined#1.7). Also, it's better to use literal concatenation than to create multiple `QStringLiteral`s and `operator+` them: `QStringLiteral(__DATE__ " " __TIME__)`.

Comment: Actually, __DATE__ and __TIME__ could be a better solution, if I always clean the project before building the solution.

Comment: @SPlatten, I've added solution for qmake pro file to rebuild "version" on each run/build

Answer (score 0):

For everyone that wants same but on windows.
Use @Xplatforms solution with **builddatetime.h** file but with the different commands:

```
WIN_PWD=$$replace(PWD, /, \\)

buildtimeTarget.target = builddatetime.h
buildtimeTarget.depends = FORCE
buildtimeTarget.commands = copy /b $$WIN_PWD\builddatetime.h+,,$$WIN_PWD\builddatetime.h
PRE_TARGETDEPS += builddatetime.h
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += buildtimeTarget
```